# Debugging memory leak issues in a Java app

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java. I'd like to help one of our teams that is working on an internal bank application. I'm one of the server support that has access to Windows and Linux servers. Anyways, the java app is running on linux. What tools would be appropriate for capturing memory leaks that can help pinpoint which code block is actually making the memory leak? Found few tools like jstat and jmap. Are these good? Is this safe to run in production? Or how would you debug an issue where cpu goes to 100%?

Comment: If you want to use these tools on production, your production server will need to run a `jdk` instead of a `jre`. Is your problem not reproducible on your local or dev machine?

Comment: According to them, it only happens in production. They also don't know what's causing it.

Comment: Before going to these tools I would 1) look for user operations that always happen before a leak manifests  2) look for resources that could be leaking such as db connections, result sets and statements that are not closed or returned to pools properly or file i/o resources that are not closed 3) look for data structures that can get big from particular user inputs